# Sql Server Error - incorrect syntax near if condition

Tags: sql-server-2008

My Query looks like below :

```
declare @test varchar(500)
 SELECT @test=coalesce(@test+',','') + cast(RoleName as varchar) FROM                                                               
        (   select roles.RoleName  from LU_BCOMS_usersroles usrroles
            inner join LU_BCOMS_roles roles 
            on roles.roleid     =   usrroles.Roles_roleid 
            where Users_Userid='MV10310'
        ) as Tbl

select repfamily.ProductName as Category,repfamily.Family as SeqChange,repfamily.RepFamily as DescOfChange, req.*,
 TaskCompVer =
 CASE WHEN req.UpdateByASPM is not null THEN  'Provide PLQM Wish List'
        WHEN req.UpdateByASPM  is null THEN 'Provide ASPM Wish List'
        WHEN req.CreatedBy is not null THEN  'Provide ASPM Wish List'
        END
  from performa.TX_BCOMS_Request as req   
inner join TX_BCOMS_Requestrepfamily family on 
family.request_requestid=req.requestid
inner  join LU_BCOMS_RepFamily as repfamily on 
family.RepFamily_repFamilyid=repfamily.repfamilyid   

where req.UpdatedByPLQM is null  
 (
   if (CHARINDEX('ASPM',@test)> 0 )
         Begin 
         and  req.UpdatedByASPM is null
         end
   else if (CHARINDEX('PLQM' ,@test)> 0)
         begin
         and req.UpdatedByASPM IS NOT null
         END 
  )
```

I am not able to build the query it's saying incorrect syntax near If can any one help me out from this..

if I met this condition if (CHARINDEX('ASPM',@test)> 0 ) I need to add in the " and  req.UpdatedByASPM is null" or else the next one ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you a expecting this ,,,

```
declare @test varchar(500)
 SELECT @test=coalesce(@test+',','') + cast(RoleName as varchar) FROM                                                               
        (   select roles.RoleName  from LU_BCOMS_usersroles usrroles
            inner join LU_BCOMS_roles roles 
            on roles.roleid     =   usrroles.Roles_roleid 
            where Users_Userid='MV10310'
        ) as Tbl

select repfamily.ProductName as Category,repfamily.Family as SeqChange,repfamily.RepFamily as DescOfChange, req.*,
 TaskCompVer =
 CASE WHEN req.UpdateByASPM is not null THEN  'Provide PLQM Wish List'
        WHEN req.UpdateByASPM  is null THEN 'Provide ASPM Wish List'
        WHEN req.CreatedBy is not null THEN  'Provide ASPM Wish List'
        END
  from performa.TX_BCOMS_Request as req   
inner join TX_BCOMS_Requestrepfamily family on 
family.request_requestid=req.requestid
inner  join LU_BCOMS_RepFamily as repfamily on 
family.RepFamily_repFamilyid=repfamily.repfamilyid   

where req.UpdatedByPLQM is null   and (

   ((CHARINDEX('ASPM',@test)> 0 )  and  req.UpdatedByASPM is null)
   or 
   ((CHARINDEX('PLQM' ,@test)> 0)  and req.UpdatedByASPM IS NOT null)
   )
```

Comment: Can u add SQlFiddle please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this where clause areas

```
WHERE   req.UpdatedByPLQM Is Null
        And 
        (CASE
            WHEN CHARINDEX('ASPM',@test)> 0 and req.UpdatedByASPM Is Null THEN 1
            WHEN (CHARINDEX('PLQM' ,@test)> 0) and req.UpdatedByASPM Is Not Null THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) = 1
```